# pip log not working in code

Tags: python, pip

```
def pib_install(self, modulename):
    pip.main(["install", "--log log.txt", modulename])
```

I have been trying to install pip modules to a remote system. This can be done through the trigger of a command on a different platform (not a SSH or anything like that)

It registers the command and runs the function seen above. The problem is that it's giving me an error that just shows me the usage of the pip install command.

```
Usage:
pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --log pem/log.txt
```

However, if you try to run the command in a normal shell, it does work.

Does anyone have an idea how I might be able to fix this?

Comment: my pip dosen't have --log option

Comment: @Zartch Are you 100% sure about that?
[Check This](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#log)

It looks like it's a general option

Comment: lie. srry :( i't works for me also.

Comment: @Zartch Could you maybe try to use it in code? So in a file, cause that's what I don't get working...

Comment: same: no such option: --log pem/log.txt

Comment: @Zartch Do you have any idea how I might be able to fix logging the pip output?

Comment: Not sure... i'm curious about it. Try to look this: http://nullege.com/codes/search/pip.log

Comment: @Zartch Wasn't able to figure it out using that link you sent...